# Duplicate Identifier 'Promise' after code analysis

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have project which builds with no error but when I run code analysis on solution I get this Duplicate Identifier 'Promise' and Duplicate Identifier 'require' errors

My visual studio version is 2017 rc

I googled solution for this, found below link
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565

Not getting any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating VS 2017 to version 15.2, I think it was bug in previous versions.